# How to strip a HTML element from a text file with PHP?

Tags: php, html, element

I am cleaning up a mess created by Adobe InDesign export feature of ePub files.

**MY GOAL:**
OPTION 1. I want to remove all `span` elements with class attribute `CharOverride-7` but leave the other span elements.
OPTION 2. In some cases I want to replace the `span.CharOverride-7` with a new element, such as `i`.

Note, my current manual and time-cconsuming way is to do mass search and replace action, but the input text file is inconsistent (extra spaces and other artifacts).

The input text contains hundreds of `p` paragraphs which look like this:

```
    <p class="2"><span class="CharOverride-7">A book title</span><a href="https://aaa.net"><span class="CharOverride-8">https://aaa.net</span></a><span class="CharOverride-7">.</span></p>

    <p class="2"><span class="CharOverride-7">Another book title</span><a href="https://aaa.net"><span class="CharOverride-8">https://aaa.net/</span></a><span class="CharOverride-7">.</span></p>
```

The desired output should look like this:

OPTION ONE (removal of the element)

```
<p class="2">A book title<a href="https://aaa.net/"><span class="CharOverride-8">https://aaa.net/</span></a>.</p>
```

OPTION TWO (replace `span.CharOverride` with `i` element)

```
<p class="2"><i>A book title</i><a href="https://aaa.net/"><span class="CharOverride-8">https://aaa.net</span></a><i>.</i></p>
```

Comment: Could probably target all `span.CharOverride-7` with an xpath. What have you tried so far? I would convert to `i` (or `em` or `strong`).

Comment: Use `DOMDocument` to parse the file. Then you can use its methods to find the elements you want, replace them, and write out the updated HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For option one this way works with using DOMDocument(): https://www.php.net/manual/de/class.domdocument.php

```
<?php
$yourHTML = '<p class="2"><span class="CharOverride-7">A book title</span><a href="https://aaa.net"><span class="CharOverride-8">https://aaa.net</span></a><span class="CharOverride-7">.</span></p>';
$dom      = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($yourHTML, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED );

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('span') as $span) {
    if ($span->attributes["class"]->value == "CharOverride-7") {
        $newelement = $dom->createTextNode($span->textContent);
        $span->parentNode->replaceChild($newelement, $span);
    }
}

$ret = $dom->saveHTML();

// <p class="2">A book title<a href="https://aaa.net"><span class="CharOverride-8">https://aaa.net</span></a>.</p>
echo $ret;
```

Comment: @user3783243 cool - didn't know about this option. I updated my answer!

Comment: Great answer. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple approach for you using [preg_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)...

```
<?php

$data = file_get_contents('[YOUR FILENAME HERE]');

$result1 = preg_replace('/<span class="CharOverride-7">(.*)<\/span>/U', '$1', $data);
//$result2 = preg_replace('/<span class="CharOverride-7">(.*)<\/span>/U', '<i>$1</i>', $data);

echo $result1; 
// echo $result2;

// Overwrite your file here... (Beyond scope of this question)
```

Just use `$result1` or `$result2` at your leisure.

[Regex101 Sandbox](https://regex101.com/r/XSapeQ/1)

Comment: Consider `<span class="other class CharOverride-7">`, `<span class='CharOverride-7'>`, and `<span id="class7" class="CharOverride-7">`, as three quick examples where this fails.. regex dont work well with HTML, and if they do they must be extensive, and on a known data set (which based on OP statement, `the input text file is inconsistent `, they do not have)

Comment: I completely disagree. This works perfectly with the scenarios provided.

Comment: Yes, this solution also works. Thank you.